# ¿Como obtener la vida media de los registro?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quiero sacar la vida media de todos los registros que existen por ejemplo si un empleador retira

**Protección para la cabeza - APRO - Casco - Steel pro - Ala completa - N/A - 5 - 30-10-2018**,

y luego al dia siguiente retira el mismo producto la vida media de ese producto es de **1 dia**.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT em.nombres, em.apellidos, re.numero_comprobante, cla.nombre AS 'clasificacion', pro.nombre_empresa AS 'proveedor', ti.nombre AS 'tipo', ma.nombre AS 'marca', mo.nombre AS 'modelo', nu.nombre AS 'talla', de.cantidad, re.f_ingreso

    FROM detalle_registro_entrega AS de 

    INNER JOIN empleados AS em ON em.id = de.fk_id_empleados
    INNER JOIN registro_entrega AS re ON re.id =de.fk_id_registro_entrega        
    INNER JOIN epp AS epp ON epp.id = de.fk_id_epp
    INNER JOIN clasificacion AS cla ON cla.id = epp.fk_id_clasificacion
    INNER JOIN proveedores AS pro ON pro.id = epp.fk_id_proveedores        
    INNER JOIN tipos AS ti ON ti.id = epp.fk_id_tipos        
    INNER JOIN marcas AS ma ON ma.id = epp.fk_id_marcas        
    INNER JOIN modelos AS mo ON mo.id = epp.fk_id_modelos        
    INNER JOIN numero_talla AS nu ON nu.id = epp.fk_id_numero_talla
```

La consulta me arroja lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cálculo de la vida media del elemento tiene como finalidad el poder conocer cuál es la vida útil de un producto entregado desde el almacén, se calcula en base a la cantidad de veces que un trabajador renueva o solicita un producto en específico : Por ejemplo si un trabajador retira un par de guantes de bodega el día 30/10/2018 y luego retira el mismo elemento el 31/10/2018 la vida media del elemento es de 1 día. Pero este dato no puede ser basado en sólo un trabajador si no que en el total de trabajadores que se encuentre en nuestra base de datos

Lo que espero es lo siguiente:

```
|clasificacion            |proveedor|tipo |marca    |modelo      |talla|dia|
|-------------------------|---------|-----|---------|------------|-----|---|
|Protección para la cabeza|APRO     |Casco|Steel pro|Ala completa|N/A  | 1 |
|Protección para la cabeza|APRO     |Casco|Steel pro|Ala completa|N/A  | 3 |
|Protección para la cabeza|APRO     |Casco|Steel pro|Ala completa|N/A  | 8 |
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y como se calcula eso? y probaste calcularlo? que tiene que ver ese query con lo que queres calcular?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer como carear un [mcve]. No creo que haga falta tantos `joins` para mostrar tu problema. También, en consultas SQL, es buena idea incluir una muestra con unas cuantas filas de la o las tablas de entrada y una muestra de la salida que se espera obtener de esos datos. Un saludo.

Comment: No se como sacar ese resultado, de diferencia de fechas para sacar que producto tiene mayor demanda

Comment: Tu redacción actual no me deja claro lo que quieres obtener. Por eso sugiero que crees un [mcve], e incluyas una muestra de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas, ya que, en estos casos, los datos dicen más que mil palabras.

Comment: Adjunto una tabla del resultado que deseo obtener

Comment: No veo como, con los datos que muestras en la imagen, se puede construir la salida que esperas. Leíste [mcve]?

Comment: El cálculo de la vida media del elemento tiene como finalidad el poder conocer cuál es la vida útil de un producto entregado desde el almacén, se calcula en base a la cantidad de veces que un trabajador renueva o solicita un producto en específico : 

Por ejemplo si un trabajador retira un par de guantes de bodega el día 30/10/2018 y luego retira el mismo elemento el 31/10/2018 la vida media del elemento es de 1 día.

Pero este dato no puede ser basado en sólo un trabajador si no que en el total de trabajadores que se encuentre en nuestra base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener lo que querés, necesitás dos campos: `fecha_ingreso` en la tabla de inventario y `fecha_salida` en la tabla de entregas. En la consulta, hacés un comparativo de las dos fechas, y así obtenés los días que el producto estuvo en la base de datos:

```
SELECT de.codigo_inventario, AVG(DATEDIFF(de.fecha_salida, in.fecha_entrada))
  FROM inventario in
 INNER JOIN detale_entregas de
      ON in.codigo_inventario = de.codigo_inventario
 GROUP BY de.codigo_inventario
```

Comment: Si yo quiero saber cual es el producto que tiene mayor demanda, no es contar los dias en que se creo el registro, me explico?

Comment: Entonces, tomás la fecha de salida del item por cada trabajador, y calculás el promedio de esas fechas usando la función `AVG()` agrupando por item

Comment: ¿Como podria hacer eso amigo?

Comment: Actualicé el código para adaptarlo a tu comentario. Estoy asumiendo que existe una tabla `inventario` donde se registra la entrada de nuevos productos

Comment: Ya lo reviso bro gracias te comentare cualquiera cosa